# How to validate a customer token in Braintree-Google Pay integration?

Tags: php, braintree, google-pay

Our implementation is as follows:

1. Authorize a credit card associated with Google Pay. Get the nonce.
2. Using the nonce received, create a Customer account. Save the token for future reference.
3. Complete transaction using saved token.

The question is how to validate the token before  starting a new transaction. Token verification is important because, transaction happens after a few days from customer creation.

Tried  `Braintree\CreditCard::find($token)`. This worked for customer accounts created with a credit card. Since we are using a nonce from Google Pay instead of Credit card, it will return a message of:

> credit card with token $token not found

How to validate a token in above case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PaymentMethod::find() will resolve the problem

Reference
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/find/php